# select vertex of graph in python igraph based on dynamic attribute name

Tags: python, igraph

I have a graph where each vertex has a list of attributes "Attr_2", "Attr_3", "Attr_4". Now I want to loop over the attributes and select the vertices based on some value. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(2,5):
    thevalue = 'test' + str(i)
    name_attr = 'Attr_' + str(i)
    ls_vertex = gr.vs.select('name_attr' == thevalue)
```

So basically on the first run, I want to select all vertices where Attr_2 = 'test2'. Next, Attr_3 = 'test3' and so on. I am not sure that my code is correct. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I guess, you need this `eval('name_attr') == thevalue`.

Comment: I need to select vertices that satisfy the condition Attr_2 = 'test2'. But since the attribute name is dynamically created, I can not use gr.vs.select(name_attr == thevalue) because igraph will treat the attribute name as "name_attr" rather than "Attr_2".